# How can I fix a ClassCastException in Hibernate when executing an HQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, hql

I'm encountering a ClassCastException when executing an HQL query in my Hibernate-based application. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode and org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generateSyntheticDotNodeForNonQualifiedPropertyRef(HqlSqlWalker.java:747)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupNonQualifiedProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:740)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1181)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1066)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:782)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:622)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at jp.assasans.protanki.server.quests.ServerDailyQuest$updateProgress$2$1.invokeSuspend(ServerDailyQuest.kt:48)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Complete code bellow: (kotlin)

```
package server.quests

import jakarta.persistence.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import server.HibernateUtils
import server.client.User
import server.extensions.singleOrNullOrThrow
import server.utils.LocalizedString

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(
  name = "daily_quests",
  indexes = [
    Index(name = "idx_daily_quests_user", columnList = "user_id")
  ]
)
abstract class ServerDailyQuest(
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  val id: Int,

  @ManyToOne
  val user: User,
  @Column(nullable = false, name = "questIndex") val index: Int, // INDEX is a reserved word in MariaDB

  @Column(nullable = false) var current: Int,
  @Column(nullable = false) var required: Int,

  @Column(nullable = false) var new: Boolean,
  @Column(nullable = false) var completed: Boolean,

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = ServerDailyQuestReward::class, mappedBy = "id.quest")
  val rewards: MutableList<ServerDailyQuestReward>
) {
  @get:Transient
  abstract val description: LocalizedString

  suspend fun updateProgress() {
    HibernateUtils.createEntityManager().let { entityManager ->
      entityManager.transaction.begin()

      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          val queryString = "UPDATE ServerDailyQuest SET current = :current, new = :new, completed = :completed WHERE id = :id"

          entityManager
              .createQuery(queryString)
              .setParameter("current", current)
              .setParameter("id", id)
              .setParameter("new", new)
              .setParameter("completed", completed)
              .executeUpdate()
      }

      entityManager.transaction.commit()
      entityManager.close()
    }
  }
}
```

The error occurs when I try to execute an update query using the following code:

```
val queryString = "UPDATE ServerDailyQuest SET current = :current, new = :new, completed = :completed WHERE id = :id"
```

And:

```
entityManager
   .createQuery(queryString)
```

The error occurs when I try to execute an update query on the **`ServerDailyQuest`**

Comment: Could be related to the use of the word "new" in entity's fields/query.

Comment: `new` is a keyword in most of the databases, what is the database that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

**Guys problem solved! I will try to explain better**

The error message received, `java.lang.ClassCastException`, indicates that there was a problem with casting types in code. Specifically, it seems that tried to convert an object of type `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode` to `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode`, but these two types are incompatible and cannot be directly cast to each other.

To fix the issue, Instead of directly executing the query using `entityManager.createQuery(queryString)`, i took the following steps:

Created a separate query object by assigning `entityManager.createQuery(queryString)` to it.

It's important to be aware that exceptions like `ClassCastException` occur when there is a mismatch between the expected types of objects. In this case, the `createQuery()` method returned an object of type SqlNode, which was incompatible with the expected type of `FromReferenceNode`. This caused the casting error.

By creating a separate query object and setting the parameters directly on it, you work around the casting issue and successfully execute the update query. Additionally, you added exception handling to catch any potential errors that may occur during the update process.

I hope this explanation helps others who may encounter a similar issue to understand the problem and implement the solution in their own code.

In short, it is linked to the incorrect use of the `entityManager`

```
suspend fun updateProgress() {
    try {
        val entityManager = HibernateUtils.createEntityManager()
        entityManager.transaction.begin()

        val queryString = "UPDATE ServerDailyQuest SET current = :current, new = :new, completed = :completed WHERE id = :id"

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString)
                .setParameter("current", current)
                .setParameter("new", new)
                .setParameter("completed", completed)
                .setParameter("id", id)

            val rowCount = query.executeUpdate()
            println("Rows updated: $rowCount")
        }

        entityManager.transaction.commit()
        entityManager.close()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        println("Error occurred while updating progress: $ex")
    }
  }
```

Using `try` and `catch` is a way to handle exceptions in code. In the provided code snippet, try and catch are used to capture and handle any exceptions that may occur during the execution of the `updateProgress()` function.

Overall, `try` and `catch` are used to provide robustness and error handling capabilities to ensure the program can gracefully recover from exceptions and continue its execution.

Hope this helps